# Why does the Azure DevOps Start link not show the project summary page any more?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

From the Dashboard in Microsoft Azure I have a list of my resources. Normally when I click on the DevOps Starter link it shows a summary page of the project with the CI/CD pipeline, the Repository and the Azure resources. I have one link that fails to show the related project information. How can I fix this issue?

Here are three screen shots showing the Starter page in question. Hope these help. No Errors were shown. Note: My other project loads correctly.

[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQlFi.png)

[Starter Loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3Yqm.png)

[Loading Complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T1vY.png)

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

After testing, the content of Devops Starter can be displayed normally on my side:

[image]

On the page, are there any warnings or error prompts regarding the display failure? It's better to share a screenshot of the actual situation for further investigation.